# Opencv Static build, jpeg,png,tiff not static linked?

Tags: opencv, build, static-libraries

I build opencv 233 as a static lib, but when i use it in my application, it gives link errors when calling cv::imwrite() that tiff,png,jasp libs are not linked. Is this the intention that i should link these my self in my app or did i build it wronge.

I would like that the 3party libs are static included in the opencv_highgui.lib instead of having to link them myself in my apps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution, if configured for visual studio 2010, the 3th party libs are not set to be linked in. Change the Link Library Dependencies to true for the highgui project.

Comment: Well I guess that is because your CMake configuration was wrong, but if not, you may want to help OpenCV by filing a bug report. +1 for answering your own question.

Comment: Maybe i set it up wronge, but I have a hard time figuring out what flag to set. (included a dump of my settings)

Comment: Thanks for posting. It seems you stumbled upon an OpenCV build system bug as you had to change the solution by hand.

Answer (score -2):

In cmake, make sure you have BUILD_3RDPARTY, or whatever it is called, checked. OpenCV will then build lib dependencies from its own tree and statically link into highgui. This is the default for Windows.

Comment: I dont see any BUILD_3RDPARTY, only WITH_JPPEG, WITH_PNG and i have checked those.

Comment: Also, in the solution all the 3th party libs are build correctly, but they are just located in a folder of their own.

Comment: The variable is called OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS. It is not too hard to use the search box in CMake, is it?

Comment: Its not there in the svn build

Comment: Found this ticket, now that i know the flag name. https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1030

Comment: Crazy stuff, I did not test the svn version. On the other hand, the ticket you found states that this flag is ignored on Windows anyway.

Comment: Yes i read that, i altered the solution files such they are static linked manual. Thanks for pointing out the OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS flag